# The Spark RDD task is in RUNNING status all the time without data processing?

Tags: apache-spark, task

[Picture：Some of the Spark RDD tasks are in RUNNING status all the time without data processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo1yB.png)

the Spark Stage is reading data from MongoDB with newAPIHadoopRDD interface, most of the tasks finished, but two tasks are in RUNNING status throughout, and the CPU and Memory of the executor is in low occupied. And I don't think it's related with Mongodb because another job reading kafka streaming has the similar behavior. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reasons. I added a static member object with init function in one Serializable class A, and one another Serializable class B instance uses the static member function F1 of the above class A, when I chang F1 to one unserializable class the problem disappeared. So I guess it's a timing sequence problem: when calling F1 the class A is not fulfilled with serializable process.